# Solr - Query over all fields best practice

Tags: xml, solr, handler

schema.xml snippet:

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
   <field name="notes" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="missionFocus" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="first_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="last_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="about_me" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="message" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
   <field name="table_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  

   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" 
          multiValued="true"/>
```

Now I want to search in all fields (except "id" and "table_type") for e.g. "hello". How I can do this? Do I really have to write following?

```
/solr/select/?q=notes:hello missionFocus:hello name:hello first_name:hello ..
```

I heard something about DisMaxRequestHandler but how I have to query with this handler? Do I need to change something in solrconfig.xml for that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best solution is to build a field, that collects the data of all fields like this

```
<field 
    name="collector" 
    type="text_general" 
    indexed="true" 
    stored="false" 
    multiValued="true"
/>
```

The only thing you have to do now is, copy the contents of all fields into that field:

```
<copyField source="notes"        dest="collector"/>
<copyField source="missionFocus" dest="collector"/>
<copyField source="name"         dest="collector"/>
....
```

Be aware that the `copyField` block has to be defined **BELOW** this:

```
<fields>
....
</fields>
```

Now you can search only on the field `collector` and you will find any text in any of your fields.

Comment: I think I already defined a "collector" field named "text"? :) Well, I just copied it from the example schema.xml.

Comment: That's right: "text" is the equivalent field in the solr example project ;-)

Comment: what to do if I want to tweak the scoring based on which field matches?

Comment: @user1925930: Actually I do not know if this is possible. I think it is not, but you better ask a separate question for this