# solr query over multiple fields doesn't work

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I have the issue that I can not query over multiple fields. I read the following article about it and did the same thing:
[Solr - Query over all fields best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practise)

here my schema file:

```
<fields>   

<field name="fileid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="doctext" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" /> 
   <field name="datecreated" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" /> 
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- catchall text field that indexes tokens both normally and in reverse for efficient
        leading wildcard queries. -->
   <field name="text_rev" type="text_general_rev" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- non-tokenized version of manufacturer to make it easier to sort or group
        results by manufacturer.  copied from "manu" via copyField -->
<!--    <field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

   <field name="payloads" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/>-->

   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>


   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />

   <dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_pi"  type="pint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />
</fields>


 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>fileid</uniqueKey>

   <copyField source="fileid" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="doctext" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="datecreated" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>

  <types>

<!-- A general text field that has reasonable, generic
     cross-language defaults: it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer,
 removes stop words from case-insensitive "stopwords.txt"
 (empty by default), and down cases.  At query time only, it
 also applies synonyms. -->
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I executed the following queries:

```
1:results = solrWorker.Query(new SolrQuery("fileid:1"));
2:results = solrWorker.Query(new SolrQuery("text:1"));
3:results = solrWorker.Query(new SolrQuery("doctext:preacher"));
4:results = solrWorker.Query(new SolrQuery("text:preacher"));
```

queries 1 & 3 are working. queries 2 and 4 are having no results.

why??

thanks,
tro

Comment: can you add the definition of text_general type ?

Comment: added! see schema file at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 thoughts about the issue.

1. You added the copy field definition after indexing the data.

   - **SOLUTION:** Reindex everything after schema changes.
2. Copy field should be inside <fields> tag. ( not sure about this, in my definition it is inside fields tag).

   - **SOLUTION:** move copy field tag inside <fields> tag.

Comment: you need to reindex everything for changes to appear after schema changes.

Comment: got it!! you saved me a lot of time!! great! thumps up :-))))