# Extending Solr Tutorial with custom fields/core

Tags: solr

After standing up a basic jetty Solr [example](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/tutorial.html). I've tried to make my own core to represent the data my company will be seeing.  I made a directory structure with conf and data directories and copied core.properties, schema.xml, and solrconfig.xml from the collection1 example.
I've editted core.properties to change the core name, and I've added 31 fields (most of type text_general, indexed, stored, not required or multivalued) to the schema.

I'm pretty sure I've set it up correctly as I can see my core in the admin page drop down and interact with it.  The problem is, when I feed a document designed for the new fields, I cannot get a successful query for any of the values. I believe the data is fed as I got the same command line response:

```
"POSTing file incidents.xml...
1 file indexed. .... 
COMMITting..."
```

I thought, the Indexing process took more time, but when I copy a field node out of an example doc (e.g `<field name="name">Apple 60 GB iPod with Video Playback Black</field> from ipod_video.xml`) into a copy of my file (incidents2.xml) searches on any of those strings instantly succeed.

The best example of my issue is both files have the field:
    `<field name="Brand" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>`
    `<field name="Brand">APPLE</field>`
However, only the second document (with the aforementioned **name** field) is returned with a query for *apple*.

Thanks for reading this far; my questions are:

1) Is there a way to dump the analysis/tokenization phase of document ingestion?  Either I don't understand it or the Analysis tab isn't designed for this.  The debugQuery=true parameter gives relevance score data but no explanation of why a document was excluded.

2)   Once I solve my overall issue, I we would like to have large text fields included in the index, can I wrap long form text in CDATA blocks in solr?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To debug any query issues in Solr, there's a few useful things to check. You might also want to add the output of your analysis page and the field you're having issues with from your schema.xml to your question. It's also a good idea to have a smaller core to work with (use three or four fields just to get started and get it to work) when trying to debug any indexing issues.

**Are the documents actually in the index?** - Perform a search for *:* (`q=*:*`) to make sure that there are any documents present in the index. `*:*` is a shortcut that means "give me all documents regardless of value". If there are no documents returned, there is no content in the index, and any attempt to search it will give zero results.

**Check the logs** - Make sure that [SolrLogging](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging) is set up, so you get any errors thrown in your log. That way you can see if there's anything in particular going wrong when the query or indexing is taking place, something which would result in the query never being performed or any documents being added to the index.

**Use the Analysis page** - If you have documents in the index, but they're not returned for the queries you're making, select the field you're querying at the analysis page and add both the value given when indexing (in the index column) and the value used when querying (in the query field). The page will then generate all the steps taken both when indexing and querying, and show you the token stream at each step. If the tokens match, they will be highlighted with a different background color, and depending on your setting, you might require all tokens present on the query side to be present on the indexing side (i.e. every token AND-ed together). Start with searching for a single token on the query side for that reason.

If you still doesn't have any hits, but have the documents in the index, be more specific. :-)

And yes, you can use CDATA.

Comment: Thank you MatsLindh for the tips

Comment: sorry, pressed enter and ran out of editting time. Thank you @MatsLindh for the tips.  1) Yes a catch all query gets both files.  2/3) While trying to understand your instructions with the Analysis page I discovered that explicit field searches work just  fine (i.e Brand:Apple). Further research indicates a query of just "apple" searches the "default field" not all fields.  What's the syntax/configuration to search all fields?

Comment: [found this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practice)

Comment: Use `qf=´ if you're using the edismax query handler, that way you can tell it which fields to query and apply different weights to each field (prioritizing title over content, etc.). Copying all fields you want searched with a particular weight to a "catch all" field is also a good idea as @David linked to.