# Solr - Default search on all fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm currently setting up a user end that requires a default search where if the field has not been specified, it should search the term across all fields instead. Would anyone know how to do this? would there be a way to do it automatically without specify each indexed field with dismax qf param?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr - Query over all fields best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practice)

Comment: @Mysterion the question maybe duplicate, but the answer is not there. The DisMax/eDisMax are also and probably a better way to go. But you are right that could be answered in the other question.

Comment: Copy every field into one field and define the copy field as the default.

Comment: @cheffe I'm fairly certain no such query parameter exists.  You either need to enumerate the fields at query time, or index a field that combines them all.  The latter being the unequivocally better solution, especially if this sort of search is going to be used regularly.

Comment: @femtoRgon we define the `qf` field of our e/DisMax Handlers within the solrconfig.xml for this matter. Then there is no need to define them at query time. This definition is taken as default for every query, if not overridden. So defined once in a XML file ... not too shabby. Especially useful if you have different analyzers per field.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this when you have dynamically generated fields as well?