# Searching all solr fields for value

Tags: solr

I want to search all fields within solr for certain value. If I search for `title:six` I receive my result, however if I search for `*:six` I don't. I've got an `all` field that collects information about all fields that are indexed, so if I search for `all:six` I do get my result as well, however I want to specifically search for `*:six`

In the schema.xml I've noticed a directive `<copyField source="*" dest="all" />` but I don't think it's working either way (well - nothing changes if I keep it, or remove it)

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr - Query over all fields best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practice)

Comment: @Mun - please tell my how that question answers my query?

Comment: just re-read your question and noticed you have an "all" field already.  I don't think you can use the specific syntax you are looking for, but if that is something you want to allow users to enter, you may want to consider transforming it server side from "*:six" to "all:six" and sending the latter to Solr.

Comment: @Mun - well, atm I'm just searching for `six`, and as `all` is indexed then it's working. The thing is that looking at the schema (not mine) it's expected that `*:six` should be working, and I want to prepare myself to answer that 1) it couldn't have possibly been working 2) it can't be done as `*:six` and doing it per either `all:six` or `six` is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search **:six* is not a legal syntax and would never work as a global search. It would most likely parse as actual text instead and search the default field for that keyword instead. If the default field (defined by **df** parameter, most likely **all**) does standard tokenization, it would split on colon and search for '*' and 'six' in that default field.

So, it may have been working as a misunderstanding of Solr syntax and could have broken at any moment. If that configuration is still running, enabling the debug flag would show exactly how to the query is parsed and against which fields it is searched. That's all the proof you would need.

The correct way is the copyField you have and declaring the field **all** as the default search field. That's how the examples that ship with Solr out of the box do it.

Comment: Excellent, adding `<str name="df">all</str>` to defaults in `solrconfig.xml` indeed solved this. I think you're right - I've not seen `*` in the debugQuery  but it might have been discarded.