# Solr: Search all fields

Tags: solr

How do I search all (dynamic) Solr fields?

I am ware of: [Solr - Query over all fields best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practice) but it simply doesn't work for me. Also, my situation might be a bit different, since I basically want the generic version of that.

I regularly have new field types, so I don't want to maintain the schema by hand. Therefore I am creating a dynamic field for everything in schema.xml:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

This works, assuming I make queries against specific fields. Since I want to query over all fields, I tried (in schema.xml):

```
<field name="all" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="all"/>
```

But my queries return nothing, even if I set the default field to my "all" field:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Core_Test/select?q=all:19&fl=id&rows=100&df=all
```

Comment: Have you checked, if the core contains documents?

Comment: Yes, if in my query I replace "all" with "MyTestField" I'm getting hits.

Comment: Have you reindexed after you added the `copyField` instruction? Also, you might want to look at the schemaless mode, at least if you want to have numeric fields usable for range queries etc. (if not, keep using what you have)

Comment: Reindexing did the trick, thanks. But schemaless mode is out of the question for the productive environment, if ".45" is the first value it will become a double field, followed by "someText" it would throw an error.