# I want to search the value over all the fields but getting following error.what will be the better approach?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am creating search using solr

I have tried this solution 
[Solr - Query over all fields best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practice)

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/sample_core: undefined field all
```

I have tried creating new field `"all"` and copied all the fields to all and searched for it but giving the above error

Comment: after adding the field "all", did you restart the server and reindex the data?

Comment: yes I did but same error

Comment: Please share your schema.xml