# How to search on all indexed fields on Solr

Tags: java, solr

I have several fields indexed on Solr and need to search on all the indexed fields.

Should I use a copyField for this purpose or is there something out of the box?

Solr documentation is not really helpful and I was unable to apply the solutions given here.

I also use SolrJ on the backend so something on that end would be helpful too.

I use Solr 7.4.0 for now.

Comment: IMHO `copyField` is the way to go. The [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833592/solr-query-over-all-fields-best-practice) is very good.

Comment: Thank you @nitrin0. This seems to work for me. I'll test it out.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to query multiple fields using natural language search is one of the key values of eDisMax. Here's an example select handler (you'd do this in solrconfig_extra.xml) where you specify 3 fields to search against (with slightly different weighting for the sake of example):

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">some_field^10 some_field2^5 some_field3</str>
        ...
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```